# noisereduce algorithm in python not working

Tags: python, algorithm, audio, pypi, noise-reduction

I've been trying to use noisereduce pypi algorithm to reduce noise for an audio file but it is giving me an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Seif Koretum/Desktop/noise_reduce/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(y=data, sr=rate)
  File "C:\Users\Seif Koretum\Desktop\noise_reduce\venv\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\noisereduce.py", line 594, in reduce_noise
    return sg.get_traces()
  File "C:\Users\Seif Koretum\Desktop\noise_reduce\venv\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\noisereduce.py", line 232, in get_traces
    filtered_chunk = self.filter_chunk(start_frame=0, end_frame=end_frame)
  File "C:\Users\Seif Koretum\Desktop\noise_reduce\venv\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\noisereduce.py", line 162, in filter_chunk
    padded_chunk = self._read_chunk(i1, i2)
  File "C:\Users\Seif Koretum\Desktop\noise_reduce\venv\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\noisereduce.py", line 154, in _read_chunk
    chunk = np.zeros((self.n_channels, i2 - i1))
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 98.6 GiB for an array with shape (220500, 60002) and data type float64
```

and my code is based on recording an audio file then remove noise then play this audio :

```
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import sounddevice as sd
from playsound import playsound
import noisereduce as nr


fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 5   # Duration of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('sample2.wav', fs, myrecording)

#SEARCH FOR NOISEREDUCE PYPI
# # load data
rate, data = wav.read("sample2.wav")
# perform noise reduction
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(y=data, sr=rate)


filename = 'sample2.wav'
playsound(filename)
```

Comment: The problem is that the algorithm is trying to allocate an array which is way to large. It seems that - for one reason or another - the amount of channels is assumes to be 220500, which actually seems to be the amount of data for a single channel. Maybe try `nr.reduce_noise(y=data, shape=(2,), sr=rate)`?

Comment: it gets an error reduce_noise() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'

Comment: Ah, I misread the documentation. Can you check what shape your incoming data has and update your post?

Comment: I actually don't know the shape .. can you tell me how can I find out or just simply copy my code and try to make it work on your IDE and tell me what is wrong with it.

Comment: I can't replicate it since I don't have access to two channels. Try `data = np.reshape(data, (2, -1))` and see if that works. Using only one channel does not raise the exception.

Comment: Thank you this worked .. but one last question how do I write the data and rate into a wav file after noise cancellation
this : write('without noise.wav',rate,data)
not working

Comment: maybe you need an underscore?  ` write('without_noise.wav',rate,data)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the reshaping suggested in the comments and then reshape back before saving:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import noisereduce as nr
import numpy as np

# load data
rate, data = wavfile.read("Why Rust (online-audio-converter.com) (1).wav")
orig_shape = data.shape
data = np.reshape(data, (2, -1))

# perform noise reduction
# optimized for speech
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(
    y=data,
    sr=rate,
    stationary=True
)

wavfile.write("mywav_reduced_noise.wav", rate, reduced_noise.reshape(orig_shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the audio to mono

```
aud_seg = AudioSegment.from_wav(wav_filename)
aud_seg = aud_seg.set_channels(1)
aud_seg.export(wav_filename, format="wav")
```