# Exporting noisereduce data in python

Tags: python, audio, noise-reduction

I'm struggling to export the noise reduced audio using the noisereduce package in Python. I found the solution for reshaping the data on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730921/noisereduce-algorithm-in-python-not-working). Can anyone help?

```
def gate2(filename):
    data, rate = soundfile.read(filename)
    data = np.reshape(data, (2, -1))
    reduced_noise = noisereduce.reduce_noise(y=data, sr=rate)     # perform noise reduction
    soundfile.write('gated.wav', reduced_noise, rate, 'PCM_16')
    return
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info! I think I don't understand the data type. The soundfile.write function is basically writing an empty file.